# How to compare two dates entered in format MM-DD-YYYY?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I receive `StartDate` and `EndDate` from the user in the shown format.

How do I compare these two dates and find `StartDate` is NOT greater than `EndDate` or the other way around?

```
set /p StartDate="Enter StartDate (MM-DD-YYYY): "
set /p EndDate="Enter EndDate (MM-DD-YYYY): "
```

Simple `"%StartDate% GTR %EndDate%"` does not work as expected.

Please direct me and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you take the dates in the format YYYYMMDD instead of MM-DD-YYYY, the dates can easily be compared as integers.

Comment: Make sense...But my requirement is to receive the date in the format MM-DD-YYYY...

Comment: Well then I recommend making a function that takes in an MM-DD-YYYY and uses string manipulation to convert it to YYYYMMDD.

Comment: Do the comparison without the dashes, `if "%StartDate:-=% GTR %EndDate-=%"`.

Answer (score 0):

What the commentators meant is using a batch code like this one:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /p "StartDate=Enter start date (MM-DD-YYYY): "
set /p "EndDate=Enter end date (MM-DD-YYYY):   "
set "DateStart=%StartDate:~6,4%%StartDate:~0,2%%StartDate:~3,2%"
set "DateEnd=%EndDate:~6,4%%EndDate:~0,2%%EndDate:~3,2%"
if %DateStart% GTR %DateEnd% (
    echo Start date %StartDate% is greater than end date %EndDate%.
) else if %DateStart% == %DateEnd% (
    echo Start date %StartDate% is equal end date %EndDate%.
) else (
    echo Start date %StartDate% is lower than end date %EndDate%.
)
endlocal
```

For an explanation of the string manipulations to convert a date string in format MM-DD-YYYY to YYYYMMDD making it possible to compare the two dates as integers or strings open a command prompt window, enter `set /?`, hit key RETURN to execute this command and read the help output now in console window for command `set`.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation. Yes it makes this easier when you convert the string format :-)